# Is there some character I can insert to get a longer pause with SAPI5 TTS?

Tags: windows-7, text-to-speech, sapi

I know the TTS system will pause on a period (.) or comma (,).  But how can I get it to pause for a longer period of time?  For example, in a question and answer scenario I want the voice to read the question and pause for moment so the listener can mentally answer the question in his or her mind and then the voice reads the answer.

I've tried stringing together a series of periods but they seem to get consolidated into one in the TTS so that they effectively pause the same length as a single period (Festival on linux did not do this, but on Windows SAPI seems to).

Is there some character or sequence of characters I can use to get a longer pause? Or alternatively another means of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 3):

Characters won't do.  Use [XML markup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to control this better, pass the SPF_IS_XML flag:

```
  HRESULT hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello <silence msec=\"1000\"/> world", 
                  SPF_IS_XML, NULL );
```

Or you can use an [SSML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/) with the SPF_PARSE_SSML flag, use the `<break>` element:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="en-US">
   Hello<break time="1000ms" />world
</speak>
```

If you can use C# then the PromptBuilder class is very handy to build the SSML:

```
    private SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

    private void sayHello() {
        var builder = new PromptBuilder();
        builder.AppendText("Hello");
        builder.AppendBreak(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        builder.AppendText("world");
        synth.SpeakAsync(new Prompt(builder));
   }
```